# Sprite in Scratch is non-smoothly "skipping" when being rotated

Tags: rotation, sprite, smoothing, mit-scratch

I am making a Squash game in scratch and I want the racket-sprite to always be straight "infront of me" as I move (with the mouse) around the court. This almost work with my code only that the racket is not rotating smoothly as I change direction but rather skipping erratically. It is difficult to see but it appears to skip between increments of 90 degrease (0, 90, 180 etc.) instead of rotating smootly between all the degrees (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 deg etc.) as I change direction. The unsmooth skipping is worse when moving slowly. Please see attched code

[image: Code for make racket sprite move ("set x to -> mouse x" and "set y to -> mouse y")and rotate (point towards -> Mouse Pointer) with cursor and]

When I take away the "`set x to (mouse x)`" and "`set y to (mouse y)`"-block it rotates nice and smoothly so it is probably something there with the interaction between these two instructions of rotating and following the cursor that causes the problem.

I have also tried for example to add "set rotation style" to all around but no differens.

https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/942479436/

Comment: Could you please share your project? I suspect that the (0,0) point of your racket's costume causes that erratic jump on rotation

Comment: I am not sure how to share the project since I cannot upload the file since it is only on my computer. What do you mean with the (0,0) point on the costume exactly. I tried moving the center (0,0) point on my costume, it did started to no longer rotate fully but it did not solve the "skipping"-problem.

Comment: You find an example on https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/942479436/

Comment: By (0,0) I meant the point around which the sprite rotates. I think I understand what you are asking: when you request the sprite to point to the left, Scratch mirrors the costume. If you rapidly switch directions (like you do) you see that mirroring going back and force. Is that it? If your racket's costume is symmetrical (horizontally), you shouldn't see that.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. the costume is horisontaly symmetrical (and I tried another sprite as well and that costume was just a horisotnal square). The costume should not just go left and right but follow the mouse smoothly in all directions. I think I have gotten the correct answer now with the suggestion to put a delay between the following of my sprite so that there is a distance between my sprite and the mouse so that I actually can have a direction between them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `set rotation style` or the `go to` block. Just this will suffice:

[image]

```
[scratchblocks]
when green flag clicked
point towards [mouse pointer v]
set x to (mouse x)
set y to (mouse y)
[/scratchblocks]
```

Comment: Thanks for code but I tried that one (also exactly like that without "set rotation style" or "go to block") but the same problem, it skips erratic between different rotation angles and also very important, when I stop the cursor movement it does not stop at the last angle but returns to the sprites default orientation/direction. If I take away the "set x/y to - blocks it does behave smoothly but not together with that "follow the mouse"-block.

Comment: @Juniper Have you tried removing just the `go to x:(0) y:(0)` block? That might help.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I have tried but that does not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

`point towards (mouse pointer)` becomes more sensitive as sprite and mouse pointer come closer together.
To make matters worse, mouse coordinates are rounded to the nearest integer value.
The slightest hand movement may cause mouse x or mouse y to change by 1.
That may not seem like a lot, but if the distance between sprite and mouse pointer is 1 or less,
then this tiny mouse movement could easily correspond to an angle of 45° or even 90°.

From your code it is clear that sprite and mouse are likely to be very close together.
The sprite is moved to the mouse position *and* is pointing towards the mouse pointer.
That is problematic; you are basically asking the sprite to point at its own location.
The only reason why there is still *some* distance between sprite and mouse pointer,
is because loops in Scratch (in this case `forever`) have a built-in delay of 0.03 seconds.
The sprite is always pointing where the mouse pointer was 0.03 seconds ago.
The slower you move the mouse, the closer the sprite will be to the mouse pointer,
and the more sensitive and jumpy the direction of the sprite will be.

There are various ways to improve this. The easiest way is to let the sprite rest when close to the mouse pointer:

```
forever
    wait until <(distance to (mouse pointer) > 10>
    point towards (mouse pointer)
    set x to (mouse x)
    set y to (mouse y)
```

Live demo: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/943574145/

Comment: Great and pedagogic answer! It does solve it, at least sort of becasue it is still not as smooth as I would like it. I experimented with the dealay time a bit and I saw that you did too becasue 10 is the best delay. Since this should theoretically solve it i wonder if there is another reason for why it still is not as smooth as I like it.